# How to make number of loaded items related to the screen size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, screen

I am using a jQuery to load latest posts in a carousel(I use the carousel from [here](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/displaying-posts-in-a-carousel/)). I use this code to set the carousel with 3 items for latest 3 posts:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#slider').carouFredSel({
        prev: '#btn_prev',
        next: '#btn_next',
        auto: false,
        items: 3,
    });
});
```

But I need to check first for the screen of the device, if small (mobile), set the items of carousel for 1 item only, if medium (tablet/ipad), set it for 2, if normal computer screen, set the items for 3. How can I make this conditional?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: Funny carousel plugin name! Who's Fred?

Comment: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/displaying-posts-in-a-carousel/

Answer (score 0):

Create a var based on screen size, and then supply it to your slider.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var itemLength = 0;
    var windowSize = $(window).width();
    if (windowWidth > 1024) { itemLength = 3 }
    else if (windowWidth > 768 { itemLength = 2 }
    else { itemLength = 1 }

    $('#slider').carouFredSel({
        prev: '#btn_prev',
        next: '#btn_next',
        auto: false,
        items: itemLength,
    });
});
```

Comment: I actually tried this but it didn't work, I dun know what might be wrong?!